# NotificationCenter Not Appearing

Tags: swift

I'm looking to create basic local notifications by passing in a string; ex "01:00 PM".  I've been trying to manipulate the following code from a tutorial, however while the print statements seem to be correct the notifications don't appear in the simulator.

```
//in ViewController

   let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

//in ViewController Extension

   func notificationRequest() { //displays correctly

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("notificationRequest approved")
        } else {
            print("notificationRequest approved denied")
        }
     }
   }

  func scheduleNotification(notifTime: String, notifTitle: String, notifBody: String) {

    let time = notifTime
    let firstSplit = time.split(separator: " ")
    let components = firstSplit[0].split(separator: ":").compactMap { Int($0) }
    let isPM = firstSplit[1] == "PM"
    let hours = components[0] + (isPM ? 12 : 0)
    let minutes = components[1]

    print("notif is  \(notifTime) hours are \(hours) minutes are \(minutes)")

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent() 
    content.title = notifTitle
    content.body = notifBody
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = hours
    dateComponents.minute = minutes

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)

    print("Notification scheduled for \(dateComponents)!")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your build target? If it's iOS 10 or newer you need to implement the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol or your notifications will not be presented.

```swift
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                       willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                       didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }

}
```

Also make sure you set the app delegate to be the notification center delegate

```swift
func notificationRequest() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: { granted, error in
            print("Notification Access Granted Status: \(granted)")
    })
}
```